# Can't load PyQGIS on QGIS3 due to problem with API version of sip module

Tags: pyqgis, installation, sip

Again having issues with building QGIS 3 on Manjaro Linux, from AUR. After solving my previous problem ([QGIS 3.0 can't load plugin processing, no module named 'osgeo', on Manjaro Linux](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276898/qgis-3-0-cant-load-plugin-processing-no-module-named-osgeo-on-manjaro-linux)), I now get the following error message:

```
Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/qgis/__init__.py", line 72, in 
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/qgis/core/__init__.py", line 34, in 
    from qgis._core import *
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.3 but the within renderer)

.. versionadded:: 2.6 module requires API v12.4


Python version:
3.6.4 (default, Jan  5 2018, 02:35:40) 
[GCC 7.2.1 20171224]

QGIS version:
3.0.1-Girona 'Girona', exported

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/thiago/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python', '/home/thiago/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/home/thiago/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

I have recompiled gdal, python-gdal, have used pip to install the latest version of sip, but I still get the same error, after several rebuilds. This error means QGIS starts without python support, making it pretty much useless for any analysis.

Comment: If you have a newer version of sip than your QGIS package is compiled against, you have to recompile QGIS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question, I switched to Ubuntu 18.04 to make it work. But for people having the same problem, there is now an experimental Flatpak version of QGIS that might minimize these dependency problems:

https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#flatpak